# Use ⌘ + tab_number to navigate to a different chrome tab

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts, slack, mac

When using the Slack web app in Chrome, how can I get `⌘ + tab_number` to navigate to a different Chrome tab? This works from any tab except for Slack web app.

This used to work but stopped working in the past few days.